# GitBucket API how to get pull request with base name

Tags: github, github-api, gitbucket

I try to get pull request with base name like below but looks like "base" query parameter not working(even head query too...).

```
http://my-gitbucket-server/api/v3/repos/test/test/pulls?state=closed&base=development&head=test:sprint0
```

[image]

How can get pull request data with "base" query parameter.(The purpose is get diff status on the pull request)

Comment: From a quick view, the head of the API URL says `test:sprint0` but the specified `base` points is `development` and not `test:development`. One of those might be wrong. It's a big confusing since it seems like your `repo` is also called `test`.

Comment: @astrochun Thank you for comment. I tried changed parameter to test:... but gitbucket always return max 25 pull requests per call. This api sounds like not working collectly like gihub api... Maybe I must find another way.

Comment: Hi, I'm a creator of GitBucket. Unfortunately, currently, GitBucket doesn't support `base` and `head` query parameters. But supporting them would be possible. I would be happy if you could open an issue for that on GitHub!